# active record sorting by two columns at same time (not one, then the other)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting

So I'm stumped on this one. I know this is dumb example, but it gets the point across.
Lets say I have a model called cars and there are three columns, personal, business, and color. The first two columns hold license plate numbers, and the last one obviously the color

Now I want to display this model in a view, buy I want to just show license plate and color, but I want to sort by license plate, no matter if its personal or business. The license plate will in only one of the first two columns.
Here is what I tried with no success, it sorts by personal lic plates first, then by business.

```
Car.all.order('personal || business') do |car|
  puts car.personal << car.business << ' ' << car.color
end
```

While it prints correctly, It wont sort like I want it. Any ideas?

Comment: what happens when you do something like: `User.all.order("personal, bussiness, color")`

Comment: That will sort by personal cars, then by business cars, ...
personal green
personal red
personal yellow
business red
business yellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can use ".order" as that effects the actual database query that is created, and as far as I know, you can't do what you want via a "simple" (rails generated) query.

But, you can sort the results after you get them from the database:

```
cars = Car.all.sort { |a,b| (a[:personal] || a[:business]) <=> (b[:personal] || b[:business])  }
```

Then use `cars.each` to loop through them.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is how I will have to do it. That will work. Thanks.for the tip